# Multiply each number / digit by increasing values

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, range, multiplication

For each digit, it must multiply that digit by `1` to `9`. Then add all these values together.

For example if the number on one line of the file is `013149498`, it should be:

```
0*1 + 1*2 + 3*3 + 1*4 + 4*5 + 9*6 + 4*7 + 9*8 + 8*9
```

Right now I have all numbers multiplying by `2`.

```
def main():
    # Open the isbns.txt file for reading.
    isbn_file = open('isbns.txt', 'r')

    print ('Here are the ISBNs')

    # Get the values from the file, multiply each by 0 to 9, then sum.
    for line in isbn_file:
        # Check if the length of the line is 10.
        size = len(line)
        print('ISBN:', size)
        if size == 11:
            for number in range(0,9):
                maths = number * 2
                print(number, maths, sep="...")


        else:
            print('ISBN invalid:', line)



    # Close the file.
    isbn_file.close()


# Call the main function.
main()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation and post the *whole* code, what is `size` for instance...

Comment: Your code says "Check if the length of the line is 10", but your check is `size==11`.  There are only 9 digits in `1-9`.  What do you expect input lines to look like?  Should the operation be applied only to the first 9 digits?  Are you doing ISBN verification?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes I am doing ISBN verification. I put size==11 because for some reason size==10 doesn't work. I am working on verifying the check digit by multiplying the first 9 numbers, then making sure the sum(261) is divisible by 11. Then I verify the check digit 8 was chosen because 261 is between 253 and 264 (multiples of 11) and 261 is 8 more than 253.

Comment: @K-py see my edit for some code more closely tailored to your situation.

Answer (score 2):

**A `one-liner`:**

I am not sure what `size` is meant to be in the code you have posted so I have removed it from my answer as I don't see it as necessary to the problem.

This will now go through every line and generate the `sum` of the `digits` in a `line` multiplied by their `position`. This value is assigned to a variable - `sm` - and then `printed` for each `line` for testing.

```
isbn_file = open('isbns.txt', 'r')

for line in isbn_file:
    sm = sum((i+1) * int(d) for i, d in enumerate(line))
    print(sm)
```

---

Obviously, I do not have access to `isbns.txt`, so I have just done a test of the `one-liner` in the interpreter with your example given in the question:

```
>>> line = "013149498"
>>> sm = sum((i+1) * int(d) for i, d in enumerate(line))
>>> sm
261
```

which seems to work fine as we can compare this to calculating the result manually:

```
>>> 0 * 1 + 1 * 2 + 3 * 3 + 1 * 4 + 4 * 5 + 9 * 6 + 4 * 7 + 9 * 8 + 8 * 9
261
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import cycle

n = '013149498'

print(sum(int(a)*b for a, b in zip(n, cycle(range(1, 10)))))
```

Here, we use `range(1, 10)` to get the integers from 1 through 9.  Then we pass that to [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to account for input strings longer than 9 characters. We then use `zip` to pair the digits of the input string with the integers from `range`.  For each of those pairs, we cast the digit to an integer, then multiply the two together. Finally, we sum the products.

Edit:

```
def validate(isbn):
  # here we split the last character off, naming it check.  The rest go into a list, first
  *first, check = isbn

  potential = sum(int(a)*b for a, b in zip(first, range(1, 10)))

  # ISBN uses X for a check digit of 10
  if check in 'xX':
    check = 10
  else:
    check = int(check)

    # % is the modulo operator.
    return potential%11 == check

#Use a context manager to simplify file handling
isbns = []
with open('isbns.txt', 'r') as isbn_file:
    for line in isbn_file:
        # get rid of leading/trailing whitespace.  This was why you had to check size == 11
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) == 10 and validate(line):
            # save the valid isbns
            isbns.append(line)
        else:
            print('Invalid ISBN:', line)
```

It's worth noting that the ISBN standard for 10 digits ISBNs seems to [follow a different standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number#Check_digits) for calculating check digits.  To change your code to follow that standard, you would substitute `range(10, 1, -1)` for the `range` in `validate`